# How to modify the time that 'date' changes (00:00:00) in an index in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date and Time           Close   dif
2015/01/01 17:00:00.211 2030.25 0.3
2015/01/01 17:00:02.456 2030.75 0.595137615
2015/01/01 23:55:01.491 2037.25 2.432613592
2015/01/02 00:02:01.955 2036.75 -0.4
2015/01/02 00:04:04.887 2036.5  -0.391144414
2015/01/02 15:14:56.207 2021.5  -4.732676608
2015/01/02 15:14:59.020 2021.5  -4.731171953
2015/01/02 15:30:00.020 2022    -4.228169436
2015/01/02 16:13:18.948 2021.25 -4.96153033
2015/01/02 16:15:00.000 2021    -5.210187988
2015/01/04 17:00:00.105 2020.5  0
2015/01/04 17:00:01.077 2021    0.423093923
```

How can I modify the index so that the current day starts at 17:00:00 of the day before and ends at 15:15:00. (Data between 15:15:00 and 17:00:00 can be eliminated).

The new dataframe would look like this:

```
Date and Time           Close   dif
2015/01/02 17:00:00.211 2030.25 0.3
2015/01/02 17:00:02.456 2030.75 0.595137615
2015/01/02 23:55:01.491 2037.25 2.432613592
2015/01/02 00:02:01.955 2036.75 -0.4
2015/01/02 00:04:04.887 2036.5  -0.391144414
2015/01/02 15:14:56.207 2021.5  -4.732676608
2015/01/02 15:14:59.020 2021.5  -4.731171953
2015/01/05 17:00:00.105 2020.5  0
2015/01/05 17:00:01.077 2021    0.423093923
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
# read in your dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('dt_data.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
df.columns = ['mydt', 'close', 'dif'] # changed your column name to 'mydt'
df.mydt = pd.to_datetime(df.mydt) # convert mydt to datetime so we can operate on it

# keep times outside [15:15 to 17:00] interval
df = df[(((df.mydt.dt.hour >= 15) & (df.mydt.dt.minute > 15)) 
                                  | (df.mydt.dt.hour == 16))==False]

# increment the day count for hours >= 17 at start of new 'day'
ndx = df[df.mydt.dt.hour>=17].index
df.ix[ndx, 'mydt'] += pd.Timedelta(days=1)

df.set_index('mydt', inplace=True, drop=True)
print(df)

                           close       dif
mydt                                      
2015-01-02 17:00:00.211  2030.25  0.300000
2015-01-02 17:00:02.456  2030.75  0.595138
2015-01-02 00:02:01.955  2036.75 -0.400000
2015-01-02 00:04:04.887  2036.50 -0.391144
2015-01-02 15:14:56.207  2021.50 -4.732677
2015-01-02 15:14:59.020  2021.50 -4.731172
2015-01-05 17:00:00.105  2020.50  0.000000
2015-01-05 17:00:01.077  2021.00  0.423094
```

EDIT: to address groupby question in comments. If you need to access only the date portion of the datetime column mydt above, you can do this:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df.mydt.dt.date)

0    2015-01-02
1    2015-01-02
2    2015-01-02
3    2015-01-02
4    2015-01-02
5    2015-01-02
6    2015-01-05
7    2015-01-05
dtype: object
```

and then you can do groupby operations using only the date portion

```
print(df.groupby(df.mydt.dt.date)['dif'].sum())

2015-01-02   -9.359855
2015-01-05    0.423094
Name: dif, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It worked Ok. The issue now is that if I try to do this: df['dif'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D'))['dif'].cumsum(), I get: 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'. It worked before.

Comment: @hernanavella see my edit above for one way to groupby the 'date' only, if that is what you are trying to do. I don't understand what you want to do with cumsum: cumsum within a day? across all days? Not sure. Maybe you can explain further or post an example of the output you want?